# JAVA - Mismatched AES key lengths

Tags: java, encryption, client-server, aes, rsa

I have two methods for ciphering/deciphering JSON messages between  Clients and a Server. The Server has a pair of RSA keys (one Private and one Public), and so does a client. In addition, both have access to a symmetric session key generated when they first establish communication, which is used to cipher the JSON message, since the channel itself is not secure. The Client generates an AES key (session key) that he then ciphers with the Server's Public Key (known to all) and sends it to the Server, who deciphers the session key and stores it in a `HashMap` under the Client's ID.

Here's the problem, though: I have checked the key length prior to sending and it is 16 bytes long. When the Server receives the ciphered session key and deciphers it, it is 24 bytes long. I assume something went wrong in between, either during the cipher or decipher operation. This is a problem because when the Client wants to start sending requests (in the form of ciphered JSON messages), the Server can't decipher and read the request, because the key has the wrong size (it throws a `java.security.InvalidKeyException`: Illegal key size or default parameters).

The cipher/decipher methods are posted below:

```java
public String cipher(Key key, String alg, String msg){
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(alg);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return encoder.encodeToString(c.doFinal(msg.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        (...)
    }
}
```

The `encoder`/`decoder` are from `java.util.Base64`.

```java
public String decipher(Key key, String alg, String msg){
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(alg);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key);
        return new String(c.doFinal(decoder.decode(msg)), "UTF-8");
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        (...)
    }
}
```

Client ciphering and sending the session key:

```java
SecretKey sk = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding").generateKey();

System.out.println(sk.getEncoded().length) //length = 16 bytes

String sessionKey = cipher(client.getServerPublicKey(),
    "RSA/ECB/PKCS5Padding", encoder.encodeToString(sk.getEncoded()));

printWriter.write("{(...), \"key\":\"" + sessionKey + "\"}");
```

Server receiving the ciphered session key and saving it in the `HashMap`:

```java
byte[] aux = decipher(registry.getServerPrivateKey(),
    "RSA/ECB/PKCS5Padding", data.get("key").toString().replace("\"", ""))
        .getBytes("UTF-8");

System.out.println(aux.length) //length = 24 bytes

registry.addSession(..., new SecretKeySpec(aux, 0, aux.length, "AES"));
```

I have tried different algorithms and different paddings, but I can't seem to figure out where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are base64 encoding your key prior to encryption with this statement:

```
String sessionKey = cipher(client.getServerPublicKey(),
    "RSA/ECB/PKCS5Padding", encoder.encodeToString(sk.getEncoded()));
```

.. making your 16 byte key into a 24 char long base64 representation. You don't need to base64 encode your key prior to encryption, as the encryption is perfectly able to handle binary data. Try with this:

```
String sessionKey = cipher(client.getServerPublicKey(),
    "RSA/ECB/PKCS5Padding", sk.getEncoded());
```

And at the same time change your `cipher(..)` methode to accept msg as `byte[]`

```
public String cipher(Key key, String alg, byte[] msg){
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(alg);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return encoder.encodeToString(c.doFinal(msg));
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        (...)
    }
}
```

also, change your `decipher(..)` to binary as well like:

```
public byte[] decipher(Key key, String alg, String msg){
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(alg);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key);
        return c.doFinal(decoder.decode(msg));
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        (...)
    }
}
```

Comment: This certainly solved the key size issue, it is now 16 bytes on both Client and Server sides, thank you! That `encoder.encodeToString(sk.getEncoded())` was the remnant of a previous implementation I had tried.